Fermat degree FRM(n)
$\DeclareMathOperator\FRM{FRM}\DeclareMathOperator\frm{frm}$Assume $\ 3\le n\in\mathbb N$.
Question:   What is the highest degree $\ f\in\mathbb N\ $ such that there does not exist any none-zero solution
$\ (\ 0\notin\{x\ y\ z\}\, )\ $ of
$$ x^n+y^n\ =\ z^n $$
in algebraic numbers $\ x\ y\ z\ $ of degrees $\, \le f$?
Such maximal $\ f\ $ is said to be $\ \FRM(n)$.
One may also consider $\ \frm(n)\ $ concerned with an infinity of solutions; hence $\ \frm(n)\ \ge\ \FRM(n)\ $ for every $\ n\ge3$.



Remarks:
The Andrew Wiles' theorem tells us that $\,\ \FRM(n)\ \ge \ 1\ $ for every $\ n\ge 3$. It easily follows that:
$$ \forall_{n\ge 3}\quad1\ \le\ \FRM(n)\ \le\ \frm(n)\ <\ n. $$


The @AlisonMiller's comment to Fermat algebraic shows that there are infinitely many solutions in numbers of degree $\le 2$ for $\ n=3\ $ hence
$$\text{Alison Miller:}\qquad \FRM(3)\ = \ \frm(3)\ =\ 1. $$
(For a specific numerical solution see
Fermat algebraic   EDIT: @GerryMyerson had several such examples earlier, see his comment and link below.)


The Pythagorean triples prove:
$$ \FRM(4)\ =\ \frm(4)\ =\ 1 $$
e.g. $\quad (\sqrt3)^4\ +\ (\sqrt4)^4\ =\ (\sqrt5)^4$.


In general, it doesn't seem that the case of composite $\ n\ $ can be totally reduced to the case of prime exponents. (?)


EDIT:
@Wojowu solved the $\,\ n:=6\cdot m\pm1\,\ $ cases (see his comment below).


Let $\,\ \left(a\ \ b\ \ c:=\left(a^2+b^2\right)^\frac12\right)\,\ $ be a Pythagorean triple; let $\ A^m=a,\,\ B^m=b,\ $ and $\ C^m=c.\,\ $ Then
$$ A^{2\cdot m} +\ B^{2\cdot m}\,\ =\,\ C^{2\cdot m} $$
hence
$$ 1\ \le\ \FRM(2\cdot m)\ \le\ \frm(2\cdot m)\ <\ m. $$
This simple partial reduction of the problem can be applied to the composite values of the exponent $\ n$.

If $\omega$ is a primitive sixth root of unity, then for any $n=6k\pm 1$ you have $1^n+(\omega^2)^n=\omega^n$. This is believed to be essentially the only nontrivial persistent solution so you may wish to exclude it, but if not, that gives $FRM(6k\pm 1)=1$.

@Wojowu, nice! ***** Re definitions, perhaps both variants should be covered by their own definitions, say FRM(n) and FER(n).

@Wojowu, I feel that your comment would gain by being an "Answer".

The number $FRM(n)+ 1$ is the more frequently studied smallest degree of a point. That $FRM(n) \leq n-2$ is obvious by intersecting with a line through a trivial point.

@ChrisWuthrich, thank you for your comment. Could you expand it for the sake of readers (like me) who are not algebraic geometers?

Some other examples of $n=3$ in quadratic fields are given at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1713770/where-fermats-last-theorem-fails/3224077#3224077

@GerryMyerson, indeed, nice examples -- simple.

In particular, @GerryMeyerson had the plus-half of the Wojowu's $\pm$-series (see Wojowu's comment and my Q. above).

Credit where it's due – that example was edited into my answer by Oscar Lanzi.
